# Cointegration test; model with different number of explanatory variables

Tags: regression, least-squares, cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller, ardl

I have run an ADF test on the residuals of an ARDL and a DOLS model to test for cointegration. I have 3 explanatory variables and 1 response variable. When I run the ADF test on the residuals on both models with all 3 explanatory variables included I get the result that they are cointegrated.

However, when I run the ADF test on the residuals of the DOLS model where only 1 explanatory variable is included I get the result that they are not cointegrated.

What could a possible explanation be of this?

Thank you!

Comment: I think your title may be a bit misleading; you have a model in each case, just a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y$ be the response variable and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the explanatory variables. It could be that the pair $(y,x_1)$ is not cointegrated while the 4 variables $(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are cointegrated. This would be the case if $y$ were a linear combination of the three $x$s plus a stationary variable, e.g. $y=x_1+x_2+x_3+\varepsilon$, where the $x$s were independent random walks.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it theoretically now but I still cannot wrap my head around it intuitively.

If $(y,x_1)$ are cointegrated it means that there exist an equilibrium in the long run, right? Well if they are not cointegrated but the model with the two other variables included are cointegrated. What can you then say about $(y,x_1)$?

Comment: @BenjaminBech, from the 4 variables being cointegrated there is not much we can say about any pair of variables being cointegrated. There could be no cointegrated pairs (as in your case), two cointegrated pairs (split the 4 into two pairs) or all possible cointegrated pairs, I think. What usually helps me is thinking constructively. Build pairs, tripples, fours etc. that are cointegrated (in possibly different ways).